# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gamingispassion/settings.production' PYTHONANYWHERE

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to host my website on pythonanywhere but after lots of trying I'm gettings this error.

This is the path of settings file:

```
'/home/gamingispassion/django_project/src/gamingispassion/settings/production'
```

I have tried 'gamingispassion.settings', 'gamingispassion/settings/production' but
not any success.

Please help me out with this problem.

EDIT: I have tried '.gamingispassion/settings/production'
and now i'm gettings this error

```
TypeError: the 'package' argument is required to perform a relative import for '.gamingispassion/settings/production'
```

Comment: have you verified the permission of the files?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You haven't given enough information here. Where are you trying `'gamingispassion.settings'`? What command gives `ModuleNotFoundError`, and what is the full error? What is the layout of your `settings` directory? Does `production.py` import from other files, or the other way around?

Comment: I have solved this issue but ran into another one. Now error is DisallowedHost, I have put hostname in Allowed_Host but still this error is not going away

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing /s and dots in your module name. If you're specifying a module for import, user only dots. For example: .gamingispassion.settings.production